# VBA: How to find all the possibilities of concatenating a string using 5 different options

Tags: vba, excel

```
' Key Ages

Dim ages(1 To 8) As String
ages(1) = "30"
ages(2) = "40"
ages(3) = "50"
ages(4) = "55"
ages(5) = "60"
ages(6) = "65"
ages(7) = "70"
ages(8) = "75"


' Gender

Dim uniorgd(1 To 3) As String
uniorgd(1) = "U"
uniorgd(2) = "F"
uniorgd(3) = "M"


' Bps

Dim Bps(1 To 6) As String
Bps(1) = "1"
Bps(2) = "2"
Bps(3) = "3"
Bps(4) = "4"
Bps(5) = "5"
Bps(6) = "6"


' UW Classes

Dim UWs(1 To 4) As String
UWs(1) = "P"
UWs(2) = "S"
UWs(3) = "1"
UWs(4) = "2"


' Marital Status

Dim MarSt(1 To 2) As String
Mar(1) = "S"
Mar(2) = "M"


' Inflations

Dim Infls(1 To 2) As String
Infls(1) = "3C_PPG"
Infls(2) = "5C_PPG"
```

So I need all the possible combinations (there are 2304) 
Then I need to use them for Vlookups, if that makes a difference.

I numbered them because I thought I could make for loops? My idea is doing something like:

```
For a = 1 to 8 
  For b = 1 to 3
    For c = 1 to 6 
      For d = 1 to 4
        For e = 1 to 2
          For f = 1 to 2 
            Concatenate(ages(a) & uniorgd(b) & Bps(c) & Uws(d) & Mar(e) & Infls(f))
          Next f
        Next e
      Next d
    Next c
  Next b
Next a
```

Is there a better way to do this? Also, where will all the concatenations go? Can I use them in Vlookup right away and record the value before moving on to the next concatenation?

Comment: the concatenation goes nowhere, since you're not saving the returned value anywhere. essentially this is "do nothing impressively" loop.

Comment: :( Okay, well how do I make it do what I want it to do?

Comment: `foo = ages(a) & uniorgd(b) etc...`?

Comment: What you have seems like the right way to go about it in VBA. Essentially this is just a big cross join across multiple tables and is probably best suited for a database, but your list of values is small, so nesting for loops seems reasonable. As @MarcB says, stick the results of your concatenation somewhere so you can use the result.

Comment: And if I wanted to look up each combination in a table, then copy them and paste them into new sheets (depending on the gender, bp, uw, mar stat, and infl -- not age), how would I go about doing that?

Comment: If you're just going to use these for VLOOKUP(), wouldn't it be easier to use MID() on the input to split out the various components?  There seems no need to create a lookup table when you know the exact format of the value and which parts of it represent which pieces of data...

Comment: Ummm I'm not sure what you mean. Basically I have a huge table where each permutation corresponds to a row (there are 2304). I need to separate this huge table into sheets based on the permutations.

What input am I splitting out using Mid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the permutations in a column of cells and use the column:

```
Sub makedata()
Dim Z As Long
Z = 1
' Key Ages
Dim ages(1 To 8) As String
ages(1) = "30"
ages(2) = "40"
ages(3) = "50"
ages(4) = "55"
ages(5) = "60"
ages(6) = "65"
ages(7) = "70"
ages(8) = "75"
' Gender
Dim uniorgd(1 To 3) As String
uniorgd(1) = "U"
uniorgd(2) = "F"
uniorgd(3) = "M"
' Bps
Dim Bps(1 To 6) As String
Bps(1) = "1"
Bps(2) = "2"
Bps(3) = "3"
Bps(4) = "4"
Bps(5) = "5"
Bps(6) = "6"
' UW Classes
Dim UWs(1 To 4) As String
UWs(1) = "P"
UWs(2) = "S"
UWs(3) = "1"
UWs(4) = "2"
' Marital Status
Dim MarSt(1 To 2) As String
MarSt(1) = "S"
MarSt(2) = "M"
' Inflations
Dim Infls(1 To 2) As String
Infls(1) = "3C_PPG"
Infls(2) = "5C_PPG"

For a = 1 To 8
  For b = 1 To 3
    For c = 1 To 6
      For d = 1 To 4
        For e = 1 To 2
          For f = 1 To 2
            Cells(Z, 1).Value = ages(a) & uniorgd(b) & Bps(c) & UWs(d) & MarSt(e) & Infls(f)
            Z = Z + 1
          Next f
        Next e
      Next d
    Next c
  Next b
Next a
End Sub
```